# How to add confirmation buttons to the WebUI-Popover jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, popover

I'm trying to get [WebUI-Popover](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover) jQuery to have confirmation buttons, one 'Save' and the other 'Cancel', so I could show/hide and run other actions against these two events!

For example: So I could send the textarea content to the server via ajax! and validate the popover to see if data was saved, if so then hide the popover, and if not then don't hide it... have it displayed still!

The popover itself works perfectly fine but doesn't have this sort of feature by default which I think it's quite important!

Here is how I am calling it;

**HTML:**

```
<table class="widget-table">
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor nova darius...</td>
    <td><button class="button button-primary button-small">Notes</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor nova darius...</td>
    <td><button class="button button-primary button-small">Notes</button></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I've got the two 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons as part of the markup!

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
        var $table = $('.widget-table');

        $table.find('tr .widget-table-note-trigger').each(function() {

            $(this).webuiPopover({
                placement: 'left',
                title: 'Notes',
                content: function() {

                    var html = '\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <textarea class="form-control">Your notes...</textarea>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="button-group">\
                        <button class="button button-round button-small button-primary">Save</button>\
                        <button class="button button-round button-small button-secondary">Cancel</button>\
                    </div>\
                    ';
                    return html;
                },
                closeable: false,
                trigger: 'manual'
            });

            //

            $(this).click(function(){

                $(this).webuiPopover('show');
            })


        })
    })();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dismissible:true` to prevent the popover from closing, and then closing it manually after the events. Remember to use JQuery `on()` if you want to attach the button to the click event

Comment: Thank you, although I had to use different plugin for this purpose, it's nice to know it's doable for future projects :) cheers